# Calling FromSql Not working on IQueryable<TEntity> after migration from Entity Framework core 2.2 to 3.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.0

I'm building my query dynamically, I have a method that receives an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` which is optional. This code used to work perfectly with EF Core 2.2 but stopped after the migration.

```
IQueryable<T> query;

if (spec.OrderedQueryable == null)
{
    query = DbContext.Set<T>()
                     .FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE RowVersion > @p0", new[] { lastRowVersion });
}
else
{
    query = spec.OrderedQueryable;
    query = query.FromSql($"SELECT * FROM {tableName} WHERE RowVersion > @p0", new[] { lastRowVersion });
}
```

The docs say that `FromSql` has been replaced with `FromSqlRaw`, that is true this works on `DbSet` but not on `IQueryable<T>`. Any hints of how can I achieve this with EF Core 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

How i got it from doc in ef core 3.0 you can't do that.

Before EF Core 3.0, the FromSql method could be specified anywhere in the query.

**New behavior**

Starting with EF Core 3.0, the new FromSqlRaw and FromSqlInterpolated methods (which replace FromSql) can only be specified on query roots, i.e. directly on the DbSet<>. Attempting to specify them anywhere else will result in a compilation error.

**Why**

Specifying FromSql anywhere other than on a DbSet had no added meaning or added value, and could cause ambiguity in certain scenarios.

**Mitigations**

FromSql invocations should be moved to be directly on the DbSet to which they apply.

Comment: Not true for my case "Specifying FromSql anywhere other than on a DbSet had no added meaning or added value", although this is not the cleanest code but saves me from writing tons of methods by just passing the query () as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use interpolation($) with FromSqlRaw() instead replace it with 
**.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM @tableName WHERE RowVersion > @p0", tablename,p0 })**